# Text change in the 'Featured' Section

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I'm trying to change the "SHOP NOW" text in the 'Featured' section, but I couldn't find it anywhere inside the HTML those words. Any thoughts on how I could change that?

This is the website link: https://www.santaclarabookstore.com.br/

Featured section code: (Full code at - https://pastebin.com/raw/TJ3hiupB )

```
<script>//<![CDATA[
imgr = new Array();
imgr[0] = "http://sites.google.com/site/fdblogsite/Home/nothumbnail.gif";
showRandomImg = true;
aBold = true;
summaryPost = 150; 
summaryTitle = 50; 
numposts1 = 10;

var _c5JhUg= "....Code String present in Pastebin link as Stackoverflow character limit was being hit....";
eval(_c5JhUg);

//]]>
</script>
```

If you need any further information or a bit of the code of the website's HTML, let me know and I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the JavaScript code which controls the text for the `SHOP NOW` button is in obfuscated form, we will first have to make the code readable. There are a variety of tools out there which can be used to accomplish this. We will utilize the Chrome Dev Tools's console and http://jsbeautifier.org for achieving this. In the end, you will have to first replace the obfuscated code -

```
var _c5JhUg= "....Very Long String....";
eval(_c5JhUg);
```

with the unobfuscated code -

```
function removeHtmlTag(_0xa164x2, _0xa164x3) {
var _0xa164x4 = _0xa164x2['split']('<');
for (var _0xa164x5 = 0; _0xa164x5 < _0xa164x4['length']; _0xa164x5++) {
    if (_0xa164x4[_0xa164x5]['indexOf']('>') != -1) {
        _0xa164x4[_0xa164x5] = _0xa164x4[_0xa164x5]['substring'](_0xa164x4[_0xa164x5]['indexOf']('>') + 1, _0xa164x4[_0xa164x5]['length'])
    }
};
_0xa164x4 = _0xa164x4['join']('');
_0xa164x4 = _0xa164x4['substring'](0, _0xa164x3 - 1);
return _0xa164x4
}

function sliderposts(_0xa164x7) {
j = showRandomImg ? Math['floor']((imgr['length'] + 1) * Math['random']()) : 0;
img = new Array;
if (numposts1 <= _0xa164x7['feed']['entry']['length']) {
    maxpost = numposts1
} else {
    maxpost = _0xa164x7['feed']['entry']['length']
};
for (var _0xa164x5 = 0; _0xa164x5 < maxpost; _0xa164x5++) {
    var _0xa164x8 = _0xa164x7['feed']['entry'][_0xa164x5];
    var _0xa164x9 = _0xa164x8['category'][0]['term'];
    var _0xa164xa = _0xa164x8['title']['$t'];
    var _0xa164xb;
    var _0xa164xc;
    if (_0xa164x5 == _0xa164x7['feed']['entry']['length']) {
        break
    };
    for (var _0xa164xd = 0; _0xa164xd < _0xa164x8['link']['length']; _0xa164xd++) {
        if (_0xa164x8['link'][_0xa164xd]['rel'] == 'alternate') {
            _0xa164xc = _0xa164x8['link'][_0xa164xd]['href'];
            break
        }
    };
    for (var _0xa164xd = 0; _0xa164xd < _0xa164x8['link']['length']; _0xa164xd++) {
        if (_0xa164x8['link'][_0xa164xd]['rel'] == 'replies' && _0xa164x8['link'][_0xa164xd]['type'] == 'text/html') {
            _0xa164xb = _0xa164x8['link'][_0xa164xd]['title']['split'](' ')[0];
            break
        }
    };
    if ('content' in _0xa164x8) {
        var _0xa164xe = _0xa164x8['content']['$t']
    } else {
        if ('summary' in _0xa164x8) {
            var _0xa164xe = _0xa164x8['summary']['$t']
        } else {
            var _0xa164xe = ''
        }
    };
    postdate = _0xa164x8['published']['$t'];
    if (j > imgr['length'] - 1) {
        j = 0
    };
    img[_0xa164x5] = imgr[j];
    s = _0xa164xe;
    a = s['indexOf']('<img');
    b = s['indexOf']('src="', a);
    c = s['indexOf']('"', b + 5);
    d = s['substr'](b + 5, c - b - 5);
    if (a != -1 && (b != -1 && (c != -1 && d != ''))) {
        img[_0xa164x5] = d
    };
    var _0xa164xf = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    var _0xa164x10 = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
    var _0xa164x11 = postdate['split']('-')[2]['substring'](0, 2);
    var _0xa164x12 = postdate['split']('-')[1];
    var _0xa164x13 = postdate['split']('-')[0];
    for (var _0xa164x14 = 0; _0xa164x14 < _0xa164xf['length']; _0xa164x14++) {
        if (parseInt(_0xa164x12) == _0xa164xf[_0xa164x14]) {
            _0xa164x12 = _0xa164x10[_0xa164x14];
            break
        }
    };
    var _0xa164x15 = _0xa164x11 + ' ' + _0xa164x12 + ' ' + _0xa164x13;
    if (_0xa164x5 == 0) {
        var _0xa164x16 = '<div class="main-post col-post"><a href="' + _0xa164xc + '"><img src="' + img[_0xa164x5] + '" alt=""></img></a><header><span><a href="' + _0xa164xc + '">Shop Now</a></span><h3 class="entry-title"><a href="' + _0xa164xc + '" title="">' + _0xa164xa + '</a></h3></header></div>';
        document['write'](_0xa164x16)
    } else {
        var _0xa164x16 = '<div class="secondary-post col-post" style="margin-right:0"><a class="hover_play_small" href="' + _0xa164xc + '"><img src="' + img[_0xa164x5] + '" height="200" width="320"></img></a><header><span><a href="' + _0xa164xc + '">Shop Now</a></span><h4><a href="' + _0xa164xc + '">' + _0xa164xa + '</a></h4></header></div>';
        document['write'](_0xa164x16)
    };
    j++
}
}
$(document)['ready'](function() {
setInterval(function() {
    if (!$('#mycontent:visible')['length']) {
        window['location']['href'] = 'http://www.soratemplates.com/'
    }
}, 3000)
});
window['onload'] = function() {
var _0xa164x17 = document['getElementById']('mycontent');
_0xa164x17['setAttribute']('href', 'http://www.soratemplates.com/');
_0xa164x17['setAttribute']('rel', 'dofollow');
_0xa164x17['setAttribute']('title', 'Free Blogger Templates');
_0xa164x17['setAttribute']('style', 'display: inline-block!important; font-size: inherit!important; color: #FFC000!important; visibility: visible!important;z-index:99!important; opacity: 1!important;');
_0xa164x17['innerHTML'] = 'SoraTemplates'
}
```

In this new code, you will find 2 instances of `Shop Now` text. Replace those with your desired text